# Jquery vertical tabs - tabs on right

Tags: jquery, css, tabs

I know how to make vertical tabs with jQuery. What I don't know how to do is make the tabs vertical *and* aligned to the right side. I don't really know much about the core of jQuery, all I know are a couple effects. Would anyone have any ideas/solutions?

Thanks in advance! - Tanner

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need jquery for vertical tabs. CSS3 has a a property for rotation http://snook.ca/archives/html_and_css/css-text-rotation . IE has a similar transform function: http://www.boogdesign.com/b2evo/index.php/element-rotation-ie-matrix-filter?blog=2 . Or you COULD use jquery: http://code.google.com/p/jquery-rotate/

Comment: I prefer to use jQuery anyway, since it's already installed. How does rotation give them the ability to be vertical?